# TimeZone.observesDaylightTime() requires API level 24; is it possible to get it in older API versions?

Tags: java, android, timezone

TimeZone.observesDaylightTime() requires API level 24. How do I get it for older APIs? Even though this is included in JAVA 1.7 Android is still complaining.

Comment: Find some library that offers that information.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do things like that in the general case. If a call requires a minimum API level you can't use it if you're targeting older API levels.

Also as one more general remark, keep in mind that Android is *not* running the "standard" version of Java - it even has [its own Virtual Machine](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/) that differs in some significant ways from the standard JVM - so the fact that something's allowed in "standard" Java doesn't automatically mean it's possible in Android. For example, it was only very recently that Android had support for Java 8 features, and even now it doesn't support *all* of the features.